# Eggplant : how to update a .csv file in senstalk

Tags: csv, eggplant

I am new to eggplant functional. Didn't find any reference to update a csv using eggplant functional.

Reference: http://docs.testplant.com/ePF/using/epf-accessing-data-cell-by-name.htm

Answer (score 0):

You can read files in and out like so, and editing a CSV is the same as other text files.

**To read a file into a variable:**

```
put file "/etc/passwd" into passwordInfo
```

**To write a variable to a file:**

```
put "0,0,0,0" into file "/tmp/testing/counters"
```

What I would do is read in your CSV and copy to a new variable, then output it. There's pretty useful syntax for moving to a specific line in your file. For example, if you wanted to increment the second column of the first row of your file "counters", you could use:
    add 1 to item 2 of line 1 of file "/tmp/testing/counters"

**All of this and more is in ["File and Folder Interaction" provided on the Eggplant website.](http://docs.testplant.com/ePF/SenseTalk/stk-file-folder-interaction.htm)**